# Pattern to get the UID inside Realtime database triggers

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

It looks like there is a closed issue on github confirming there is no official way to get the identity of user who triggered real time database onCreate/onUpdate and onDelete.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/133

For onCreate and onUpdate scenarios, I'm handling it by adding a required uid field on the model and validating it against firebase auth by a database rule.

```
"uid":{
      ".validate": "auth.uid === newData.val()"
 }
```

With that change, functions can find uid by simply calling `event.data.val().uid` inside the function code.

This wouldn't work for onDelete scenario, as there is no data for deleted records. I have looked into options like adding markForDelete field on the model, but at that point it looked like a hack.

Which pattern are you using in your projects for onDelete scenario if you need the uid of the user who triggered the event and don't want to use undocumented event.auth api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the uid of the user in the path of the node you create/update/delete:

```
/path/to/{uid}
  - property1
  - property2
```

It will always be present in the event no matter what the operation is.  You can also protect it with [user-based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Also consider having a dedicated space for pushing commands on a per-user basis, to be handled by a function trigger.  I talk about that in my [session at I/O 17](https://youtu.be/eWj6dxfN63g?t=11m30s).

Comment: Neat! Thanks for sharing again.